# java basics static method

Tags: java, static

can a static method be invoked before even a single instances of the class is constructed?

Comment: When learning java, one of your first encounters with static concepts is the use of System.out.println().  It is an interesting bit of code, in particular System and System.out; let alone the implementations of println().

Answer (score 11):

absolutely, this is the **purpose** of static methods:

```
class ClassName {

     public static void staticMethod() {

     }
}
```

In order to invoke a static method you must import the class:

```
import ClassName;
// ...
ClassName.staticMethod();
```

or using static imports (Java 5 or above):

```
import static ClassName.staticMethod;
// ...
staticMethod();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is exactly what static methods are for.

```
ClassName.staticMethodName();
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have already suggested, it is definitely possible to call a static method on a class without (previously) creating an instance--this is how Singletons work.  For example:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
public class MyClass 
{
    // the static method Calendar.getInstance() is used to create 
    // [Calendar]s--note that [Calendar]'s constructor is private
    private Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
}
```

If you mean, "is it possible to automatically call a specific static method before the first object is initialized?", see below:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // the static block is garanteed to be executed before the
    // first [MyClass] object is created.
    static {
        MyClass.init();
    }

    private static void init() {
        // do something ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because static methods cannot access instance variables, so all the JVM has to do is run the code.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods are **meant** to be called without instantiating the class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access it by writing `ClassName.methodName` before creating any instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not only can you do that, but you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there are a lot of "utility classes", like `Math`, `Collections`, `Arrays`, and `System`, which are classes that cannot be instantiated, but whose whole purpose is to provide static methods for people to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's definitely possible. For example, consider the following example...

```
class test {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
 }
```

...if then we run it, it does execute, we never created a instance of the class test. In short, the statement `public static void main(String arg[])` means execute the main method without instantiating the class `test`.